# Apparent power for assymetric configurations

Tags: power, ac, three-phase

I know that the total apparent power S in a 3 phase load for Wye-Wye or D-D configuration = sqrt(3)Vline*Iline.

Is it the same for Wye-D or D-Wye configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

For a Wye source with a balanced load you also have $$S = 3V_{phase}I_{line}$$

where \$V_{phase}\$ is the voltage between any one phase and neutral.

(\$V_{line}\$ is, of course, the voltage between any two phases.)